# Python: How can I change the instance of an object on change of its attribute?

Tags: python

I have created a custom object and I want it to return a new instance of the object every time you call one of its methods or preferably, change some attribute. IE

```
>>> A = Class1("I am A")
>>> B = A.setString("I am B")
>>> A.getString()
"I am A"
>>> B.getString()
"I am B"
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Furthermore I have a list of subclasses in my object, when I change the subclass object I also want the instance of the parent class to change aswell. For example:

```
>>> C = Class2(A) 
>>> D = Class2.getClass1().setString("I am B")
>>> C.getClass1()
"I am A"
>>> D.getClass1()
"I am B"
```

Is there a good way to do this stuff? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us some code that you tried, and what went wrong?

Comment: `A.setString("I am B")` should just return a new instance, no? So `def setString(self, string): return A(string)`. note, python conventionally uses `snake_case` not `camelCase`

Comment: I am confused by the mismatch between the title of the question and the question body. What does it mean to "change the instance of the object"? The object `A` doesn't change at all.

Comment: @MarcosModenesi Yeah I meant "How can I create a new instance of an object on change of its attribute"

Comment: @GenoSen I see! then the answers bellow should help. As a python dev, though, I would be deeply confused to use or interact with code like that. A method `set_something` returning a new instance (and not modifing the original instance at all). Maybe you are coming from a different programming language (I bet C++) where classes matter more.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
class Class1:
    def __init__(self, string):
        self.string = string
    def set_string(self, string):
        return Class1(string)
    def get_string(self):
        return self.string
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you could have multiple implementations of what you're asking. You might want to tell us what you want to do instead. It might be a XY problem.

Here is my contribution :

```py
from copy import deepcopy

class Test:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return "I am {}".format(self.name)

    def set_name(self, name):
        new = deepcopy(self)
        new.name = name
        return new

if __name__ == '__main__':
    A = Test("A")
    B = A.set_name("B")
    print(A) # I am A
    print(B) # I am B
```

Comment: I am currently doing what you are doing in the set_name method. But I was hoping there was a way to do it without copying the parent class in every method. Something like using getattr to create a new instance then call the method in question. This gettattr solution will however will create an infinite recursion problem.

Comment: If what you want is to "make a new object while altering one or some of its current state", I don't think you've got another choice. Why does deepcopy bothers you ?

Comment: Well I have a parent Object that has a list of custom objects I created. Each of these objects has a reference to the parent object as a parameter. Everytime I change these objects I also have to recursively go through the parent objects list and change the reference to the new changed object. I was hoping to find a better way to do this. If I simply allow the reference to change the code is much cleaner but it doesnt really achieve the outcome I want.

Comment: To add to my previous comment, the outcome in question is that, my variable names describe the object like so: v_no_2 = 2. v_no_4 = v_no_2 + 2, in this case v_no_4 = 4 and v_no_2 is still 2, but in my case whenever I do v_no_2 + 2, v_no_2 equates to 4 if I let the reference stay the same when using __add__, however if I try to do what you do I get the mess above which works but doesnt seem that eligant